# Javascript: Change a function parameter that has a default value without having to change the preceding ones

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, default-parameters

How to modify a default parameter in a javascript function, knowing that the previous parameters must remain default?

```js
function f(a = 'a', b='b', c='c') {
  return [a, b, c];
}

f( c ='some value here'); //must return ['a', 'b', 'some value here']
```

I want something similar to what can be done in python.

```py
def f(a = 'a', b = 'b', c ='c'):
    return [a, b, c]

f(c = 'some value here') #will return ['a', 'b', 'some value here']
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: `f(undefined, undefined, 'some value here')`